# Save just an integer into .txt Android

Tags: android, integer, save

In my application i have to save just an int variable like "score" or "level" so that the progress of the users doesn't go lost.
I tried to parse from a String but it doesn't work for me.
I also tried:

```
private int readFromFile() {

   Scanner getScore= new Scanner(STORETEXT);
    punteggio=getScore.nextInt();
return score;

    }
```

where SCORETEXT has been defined:

```
  private final static String STORETEXT = "score.txt";
```

If i put into the OnCreate:

```
  int points= readfromFIle();
```

The app crashes.

1) Can you tell me what's the source code to read a Int?

2)I would like to know how to write it to .txt too, just to be sure the code i am using for writing is correct.

Comment: You might consider using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) instead of standard File access for this.

Comment: Thanks, i tried with sharedpreferences, but the syntax is quite difficult and i don't know how to fit it for int variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in use SharedPreferences. Your app crashes because of empty string resource.

```
<string name="scoreNow">HERE MUST BE YOUR STRING VALUE</string>
```

Name attribute in  tag is only an identifier, not a value.

But in fact, you shouldn't use strings in resources as key for some value. String resources are needed for localization. Keys for SharedPreferences and same classes better to be constant fields in class. For example, for your code:

```
public class Storage {

    //...

    private static final String SCORE_KEY = "score";

    public void saveScore(int score) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt(SCORE_KEY, scoreValue);
        editor.apply(); //apply is better than commit in fact
    }

    public int readScore() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int scoreValue = sharedPref.getInt(SCORE_KEY, 0);
        return scoreValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I agree with you in some way. 
In fact, I don't understand, why Google use such a sample, for me constants is better - because resources are some global information, and we should reduce scope of values. A fortiori, if preferences is logically assigned to some class.

P.S. strings in resources are also for some API key and etc. and may be for some very important prefs for app - but not for all - it's as for me.